# Wont port forward, what im i doing wrong?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, portforwarding

So most of my time using Ubuntu 20.04 server I've never had a problem with port forwarding, it was always simple, go to your wifi admin page, open the port to the right ip, go to the server and make sure to write sudo ufw (port). I've been doing that the whole time but now suddenly after I reset one of my servers and installed WordPress, mysql and maria I couldn't port forward. I'm not sure if the stuff that I downloaded had anything to do with it but its very strange. Any help would be much appreciated, if you need me to send any info in the comments just let me know.

sorry about my English, I'm not so good at it.

Comment: Ensure that the ports are being listened to by the correct processes: `sudo lsof -i -P | grep <port>`. Also check the list of firewall rules: `ufw list`.

Comment: did this and it does show up, port still not open. and it was being listened to by the right process.

Comment: You can then try accessing the ports (e.g. `curl <host>`) from `localhost`, the local network, and from outside the network. If only the last one doesn't work, check the router config and logs.